# When to use OpenMP vs DoParallel?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcp, parallel.foreach, doparallel

For a `for` loop in R that is parallelized with `DoParallel::foreach`, is there any advantage to porting the code to Rcpp and using OpenMP to do the parallelization instead?  Assuming that the code itself runs equally fast in R and C, are there any speed gains to be expected?

Comment: I think people typically see speed gains with for loops in ```Rcpp``` so I am not sure it is safe to assume that the loops are equally fast in R and C++. But to hedge the statement, I have no idea what you are performing in the loops. It might be better if you had a small example use case; you could also probably profile it as well.